# checksum calculation using ArraySegment<byte>

Tags: c#

I have issue with the following method - I don't understand why it behaves the way it does

```
private static bool chksumCalc(ref byte[] receive_byte_array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("receive_byte_array -> " + receive_byte_array.Length); //ok,151 bytes in my case
    ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(receive_byte_array, 0, 149);
    Console.WriteLine("segment # -> " + segment.Count); //ok,149 bytes

    BitArray resultBits = new BitArray(8); //hold the result
    Console.WriteLine("resultBits.Length -> " + resultBits.Length); //ok, 8bits
    //now loop through the 149 bytes
    for (int i = segment.Offset; i < (segment.Offset + segment.Count); ++i)
    {
        BitArray curBits = new BitArray(segment.Array[i]);
        Console.WriteLine("curBits.Length -> " + curBits.Length); //gives me 229 not 8?
        resultBits = resultBits.Xor(curBits);
    }

    //some more things to do  ... return true...
    //or else
    return false;
}
```

I need to `XOR` 149 bytes and I don't understand why `segment.Array[i]` doesn't give me 1 byte. If I have array of 149 bytes if I use for example `segment.Array[1]` it has to yield the 2nd byte or am I that wrong? Where does the 229 come from? Can someone please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are creating the `BitArray` with this constructor: [BitArray Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ty2t3fx(v=vs.110).aspx). I think you want `new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(segment.Array[i]));`

Comment: @Johnny Mopp - it gives curBits.Length -> 16 now. I still don't get why it's not 8

Comment: It's not 8 because the value at that position in the array is 16, so that constructor will create a `BitArray` that can contain that many values.  See my answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. Looking at the [BitConverter.GetBytes MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) there is no overload that accepts a `byte`.

Comment: Calling `BitConverter.GetBytes(segment.Array[i])` is a bit silly, since you're starting out with a byte already.  It can be used to expand a 64-bit long value into an array of bytes, but it has no application here.

Comment: @Amy Indeed - it is. Thank you for your answer (works fine) and your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the constructor you're calling:  [BitArray(int length)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ty2t3fx(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the BitArray class that can hold the specified number of bit values, which are initially set to false.

If you look, [all of the constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) for `BitArray` read like that.  I don't see why you need to use the `BitArray` class at all, though.  Just use a `byte` to store your XOR result:

```
private static bool chksumCalc(ref byte[] receive_byte_array)
{
    var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(receive_byte_array, 0, 149);
    byte resultBits = 0;
    for (var i = segment.Offset; i < (segment.Offset + segment.Count); ++i)
    {
        var curBits = segment.Array[i];
        resultBits = (byte)(resultBits ^ curBits);
    }

    //some more things to do  ... return true...
    //or else
    return false;
}
```

I don't think you need the `ArraySegment<T>` either (not for the code presented), but I left it as is since it's beside the point of the question.

Comment: No I don't need it - I removed it. Thx again.